# How do I configure a logs-based metric to sum some values from log messages?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-cloud-logging, google-cloud-monitoring

I'm having trouble wrapping my head around GCP Logs Based Metrics. I have the following messages being logged from a cloud function:

```sh
insertId: qwerty
jsonPayload:
  accountId: 60da91d2-7391-4979-ba3b-4bfb31fa7777
  message: Replay beginning. Event tally=1
  metric: stashed-events-tally
  tally: 5
labels:
  execution_id: n2iwj3335agb
```

What I'd like to do is sum up the values in the `tally` field. I've looked into logs based metrics and most of the examples I've seen seem to concern themselves with COUNTing the number of log messages that match the given filter. What I need to do is SUM the `tally` value.

Here's what I have so far (I'm using terraform to deploy the logs based metric):

```hcl
resource "google_logging_metric" "my_metric" {
    name = "mymetric"
    filter = "resource.type=cloud_function AND resource.labels.function_name=${google_cloudfunctions_function.function.name} AND jsonPayload.metric=stashed-events-tally"
    metric_descriptor {
        metric_kind  = "DELTA"
        value_type   = "DISTRIBUTION"
        display_name = "mymetric"  
    }
    value_extractor = "EXTRACT(jsonPayload.tally)"
    bucket_options {
    linear_buckets {
      num_finite_buckets = 10
      width              = 1
    }
  }
}
```

Do I have to do something specific to SUM those values up, or is that defined wherever the metric is consumed (e.g. on a monitoring dashboard)?

As I say, I'm having trouble wrapping my head around this.

Answer (score -3, accepted):

When you instrument your code, you have 2 steps:

- Get the metrics
- Visualize/create alert on metrics

The Log-based metric simply converts a log in a metric.

Then, if you want to perform a sum (over a time window of course), you have to ask your dashboarding system to perform that operation, with Cloud Monitoring for instance

Comment: How is it possible to get the dashboard from log metric. I am trying to do the same but couldn't find anything useful.
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77651621/creating-monitor-dashboard-using-cloud-run-service-logs

Comment: Does anyone have an actual answer on how to actually DO it? With, as this person suggested, Cloud Monitoring?

Comment: I don't understand the question. When you have your metric, you can create a chart (with sum, avg, aggregation,...), and add charts to dashboards. Where is the blocker?